# call visibility from another activity - Android

Tags: android, visibility

I have two activities in my project, Activity_one.xml contains the ProgressBar and checkboxes and i know i can call the visibility method from the same activity but i want to implement the visibility method in Activity_two.java. how do i do that?

```
progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });
    }

    public void updateProgressBars() {

      progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }

    }
```

Comment: Look into fragments. A fragment is an implementation that allows you to place a functional piece of code in multiple classes with ease.

Comment: can you tell me how to implement it ? in the activities Thanks